# pivotitem.visibleの設定

Tags: excel

pivotitem.visibleがデバック時にintegerで表示される。true,false
が設定できない。excel VBA 2010

Answer (score 0):

国外のサイトで回答らしきものを見つけました。
引用せずの記載は、御容赦願います。ありがとうございました。

pivotfieldに指定しているデータが日付形式の場合に発生します。
特にUS以外のロケールの場合に同じ現象になるようです。

別名の列を作成して、対象データを文字列yyyy/mm/ddのデータに変換する。
作成した別名のpivotfieldを使用する。
pivotitem.visibleにtrue、falseが設定出来る様になります。

IDEでpivotitem.visibleが、integer表示される部分は、変化しません。